# c/c++ libpdel XML conversion

Tags: c++, c, xml, struct

I'm using libpdel library for parsing a C struct (that contains an array of struct) in XML.
I followed the example in "structs.h" for converting my struct in pdel format, but when I execute my program, it prints initial row in XML and then it stops with this error :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

`<Topology>`

```
<nodes>5</nodes>

a.out: ./structs/type/structs_type_struct.c:42: structs_struct_init:


Assertion `field->size == field->type->size' failed.
```

I wrote my structs in this way:

```
 struct topologyLink{ 
    int capacity;
    int used;
    char srcAddr[CHAR_ADDRESS];
    char dstAddr[CHAR_ADDRESS];
    char srcInterface[CHAR_INTERFACE];
    char dstInterface[CHAR_INTERFACE];
};
struct xmlRoot2{ 
    int nodes;
    struct topologyLink *xmlVector; //array of topologyLink struct
}*xmlStruct;
```

Following example in structs.h of libpdel, I tryed to convert them with this code:

```
// Descriptor for 'struct xmlLink'
static const struct structs_field topologyLink_fields[] = {
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(topologyLink, capacity, &structs_type_int),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(topologyLink, used, &structs_type_int),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(topologyLink, srcAddr, &structs_type_string),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(topologyLink, dstAddr, &structs_type_string),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(topologyLink, srcInterface, &structs_type_string),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(topologyLink, dstInterface, &structs_type_string),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD_END
};
static const struct structs_type topologyLink_type =
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_TYPE(topologyLink, &topologyLink_fields);

// Descriptor for a variable of type 'struct xmlLink *'
static const struct structs_type xmlVector_ptr_type =
        STRUCTS_POINTER_TYPE(&topologyLink_type, "struct xmlVector");

// Descriptor for 'struct xmlRoot2'
static const struct structs_field xmlRoot_fields[] = {
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(xmlRoot2, nodes, &structs_type_int),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD(xmlRoot2, xmlVector, &xmlVector_ptr_type),
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_FIELD_END
};
static const struct structs_type xmlRoot_type =
        STRUCTS_STRUCT_TYPE(xmlRoot2, &xmlRoot_fields);
```

Then, I passed the converted structs by calling the function

```
structs_xml_output(&xmlRoot_type, "Topology", NULL, xmlStruct, stdout, NULL, 0);
```

Can anyone help me?